# Unsure of access 97 syntax

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I am using *Access 2013*, and I am working with a access file from 97. So it has been converted from 97 to 03, and 03 to 07 and now I am opening it with *Access 2013*. The developer before me coded criterias that have syntax like this `[Forms]![frmSearch]![txtboxSearch]`.

From what I understand, frmSearch is a form in this access file, `txtboxSearch` is a `textbox` field a user can enter a date into...What I don't understand is why is there [] around everything and ! in the middle. Also why is there `[Forms]` in the beginning?.

I have tried googling access syntax of 97 but could not find anything related.

Also one last thing, whenever I try to run these queries, my parameter textbox displays `Forms!frmSearch!txtboxSearch` which I also am not too sure why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretend you have a query with a criterion such as this ...

```sql
WHERE some_field = [Forms]![frmSearch]![txtboxSearch]
```

That asks the db engine to give you the rows where the value of *some_field* is equal to the value contained in a control named *txtboxSearch* on a form named *frmSearch*.

In order for that to work, *frmSearch* must be open in Form View.  If the form is not open, the db engine won't find a value for *txtboxSearch* and will then ask you to supply the value.

You also asked about the `[]` characters.  Those would not be required with your form and control names.  So, if the first `WHERE` clause worked, this one would, too ...

```sql
WHERE some_field = Forms!frmSearch!txtboxSearch
```

But, if one of those names matched a reserved word or included troublesome characters, the square brackets would signal the db engine that whatever was found between the `[]` is an object identifier.

The `!` means "member of".  So `[Forms]![frmSearch]![txtboxSearch]` means "look in the Forms collection for a form named *frmSearch* and reference the value of one of that form's controls named *txtboxSearch*".

That was a simple overview, but there can be other details which may cause trouble.  For example, if you are using the query as the data source for a recordset, Access may not recognize `[Forms]![frmSearch]![txtboxSearch]` even if the form is open in Form View.

If you still have trouble, tell us about how you're attempting to use the query.

Comment: Ok I think I understand a little more, this will be a different exercise.. on my form, Have 2 input boxes for start and end date, I enter those with the form open, I click a run button that executes a macro which uses a query to create a new table and display information within the start and end date. This all works fine but even with text in my input boxes, on the button click it asks for the same parameters again but it displays "Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxStartDate" and "Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxEndDate"

Can I make that text atleast say something like "Start" and "End"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost now.  Since you're still being asked for parameter values, what do you get by running this statement in the Immediate window when the form is open? ... `? Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxStartDate`

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean? When The form is open I have 2 input labels that I enter my dates in, when I click on the button, I get a message box saying "You are about to run a make-table query that will modify date in your table" which is expected, the next 2 windows that popup ask for "Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxStartDate" and "Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxEndDate" it seems repetitive to having to insert these two times, and in a weird string like that

Comment: Perhaps the Immediate window is unfamiliar to you?  If so, press Ctrl+g, then type `? Forms!frmBldgsCondemned!tbxStartDate` and press enter.  What happens?

Comment: Ohh I didn't know about that, that is a cool little debugger, thank you so much! It returns my string values i enter as dates for both of the labels. I also noticed that the parameter frmSearch was incorrectly names and I changed the name and now it doesn't ask for the second set of parameters! thanks for points me in the right direction and this has been fixed thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets allow you to use names which have embedded spaces. The `!` symbols are a special VBA syntax which essentially means "call the default "get item" method on the object on the left, and use the string on the right as the key for that method.

You only need square brackets, because you are using the `!` syntax. The string you have given me evaluates to:

```
Forms.Item("frmSearch").Controls("txtboxSearch")
```

I would change this to the dot (`.`) syntax, which uses directly early binding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems as if your . syntax method isn't accepted in access 2013 when I try to use it, it says there is an invalid operator.